# Switching to use Interleaved VBO's - compiles but nothing is drawn - opengl es 2.0

Tags: java, android, rendering, opengl-es-2.0, vbo

I have just tried switching to use Interleaved VBOs. I have stepped through the process of creating the Interleaved VBO and it appears that it has the correct information init.

VVV NNN TT etc.

Here is the code for initialising the buffer

```
VertexBuffer = Loader.vertexBuffer;     

final int buffers[] = new int[1];
GLES20.glGenBuffers(1, buffers, 0); 

GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[0]);
GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexBuffer.capacity(), VertexBuffer, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);  

GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

mBufferIdx = buffers[0];    

VertexBuffer.limit(0);
VertexBuffer = null;
```

and here is my code for drawing the model

```
final int stride = (mPositionDataSize + mNormalDataSize + mTextureCoordinateDataSize) * mBytesPerFloat;

// Pass in the position information
GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mBufferIdx);
GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, mPositionDataSize, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, stride, 0);

// Pass in the normal information
GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mBufferIdx);
GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mNormalHandle);
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mNormalHandle, mNormalDataSize, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, stride,   mPositionDataSize * mBytesPerFloat);

// Pass in the texture information
GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mBufferIdx);
GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mTextureCoordinateHandle);
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mTextureCoordinateHandle, mTextureCoordinateDataSize,  GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
stride, (mPositionDataSize + mNormalDataSize) * mBytesPerFloat);


// Clear the currently bound buffer (so future OpenGL calls do not use this buffer).
GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

// Draw .
GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, NumVertices);
```

I left the matrices work out as this worked before using VBOs and i am seeting all the handles correctly.

My app appears to run as if the models are there but just invisible. for example i am moving a model and being told when it gets to a certain position, i just cant see it like i did before i moved to VBOs.

Let me know if i need to upload anything else. Any advice would be appreciated.

UPDATE!

I think the issue maybe in the way i create the interleaved VBO here is the code

```
private void createVertexBuffer(float[] VertexList, float[] NormalList, float[] TextureList)
{
    final int vertexDataSize = VertexList.length + NormalList.length + TextureList.length;
    this.vertexBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertexDataSize * mBytesPerFloat).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();

    int PositionOffset = 0;
    int NormalOffset = 0;
    int TextureOffset = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < NumVerts; i++)
    {                       
        this.vertexBuffer.put(VertexList, PositionOffset, mPositionDataSize);
        PositionOffset += mPositionDataSize;
        this.vertexBuffer.put(NormalList, NormalOffset, mNormalDataSize);
        NormalOffset += mNormalDataSize;
        this.vertexBuffer.put(TextureList, TextureOffset, mTextureCoordinateDataSize);
        TextureOffset += mTextureCoordinateDataSize;            
    }
    this.vertexBuffer.position(0);
}
```

What could i be doing wrong?

UPDATE CODE

```
 mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramHandle, "u_MVPMatrix");
    mMVMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramHandle, "u_MVMatrix");
    mLightPosHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramHandle, "u_LightPos");
    //mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgramHandle, "a_Color");

    Cube1.mTextureUniformHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramHandle, "u_Texture");
    Cube1.mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgramHandle, "a_Position");
    Cube1.mNormalHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgramHandle, "a_Normal");
    Cube1.mTextureCoordinateHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgramHandle, "a_TexCoordinate");

 Cube1.SetTexture();
    Cube1.SetIdentity();
    Cube1.SetPosition();
    Cube1.SetScale(10.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f);
    Cube1.SetRotation(RotationAngle, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    Cube1.DrawModel(mProjectionMatrix, mViewMatrix, mMVPMatrix, mMVPMatrixHandle, mMVMatrixHandle, mLightPosHandle, mLightPosInEyeSpace); 

public void SetTexture()
{
    // Bind the texture to this unit.
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureDataHandle); 
    // Tell the texture uniform sampler to use this texture in the shader by binding to texture unit 0.
    GLES20.glUniform1i(mTextureUniformHandle, 0);
}
```

Comment: I rob, it seems there is some kind of problems in the stride/size offset you set in the different VertexAttribPointer. Can you report the way you set the different mPositionDataSize , mNormalDataSize, mTextureCoordinateDataSize. The function parameters (very dirty way to calculate it) should be 0 x sizeof(float), 3 x sizeof(float), 6 x sizeof(float). Something like this. Try to check or report these 2 variables. Ciao. Maurizio

Comment: Hi @MaurizioBenedetti i set these as final ints at the start of the class private final int mBytesPerFloat = 4; 
 private final int mPositionDataSize = 3;  
 private final int mNormalDataSize = 3;
 private final int mTextureCoordinateDataSize = 2;

Comment: when you say it is a very dirty way to calculate it (meaning the createvertexbuffer method?) Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: @MaurizioBenedetti I have checked the buffer and the way that i fill it. i dont think the issue is there so i am back to the stride/size. do you have any more advice?

Comment: Hi Rob.
I have been reviewing your code once again, it all looks good. Just a quick note, where do you bind the texture? Since your are passing the texture coordinates I guess that the frag_color is computed based on the texture. I cannot see in your code the shader or the texture binding. I suggest to review that part. In case you are using shaders, you could try very simply to force the frag_color to a fixed value (i.e. white for black screen or black for white screen) to see if at least the geometry information are handled.

Comment: @MaurizioBenedetti thanks for the response i have updated with the code above starting with some of the onDraw then the function that sets the texture. i realise i need to organise this better however when using seperate buffers this did all work ok. Thanks

Comment: I have added my parser to here http://pastebin.com/WN6KKqKE    when i debug after filling the vertex and index buffer i notice 2 things the raw data does not match what is put in to the vertex buffer (is this because it is a byte buffer? and two the indexBuffer has a 0 after each value, is this normal behaviour and am i correctly using the VB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what my issue was in the above code how ever i re wrote my code to use an index buffer and have submitted in another question. Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22997256/opengl-es-2-0-populating-the-vertex-and-index-buffer)

Along with the answer i gave in the other question it should give a clear way of introducing VBO's and IBO's for any one who is struggling